# How to remote debug a par file?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, bazel

We use https://github.com/google/subpar to generate a par file for our python code using bazel.
How can I configure pycharm to understand par file?
The par file is essentially all the code put in a single file created to run like an executable.
When I connect pycharm to a remote process, the debug break point hits, but pycharm is not able to understand or map the file to the workspace

Answer (score 0):

The par file self-extracts its runfiles to an ephemeral [temporary directory](https://github.com/google/subpar/blob/1f695ee5d42585a66d9dd9b71219eb8551e59c89/runtime/support.py#L38), which it also uses the working directory. If you can figure out the path to that directory (it's different every time) you could probably add it as a [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html) to Pycharm.

Comment: is there a way to specify this path?